# Is there a way to detect swipe down action on a SliverAppBar?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a SliverAppBar and I want to detect swipe down actions on the same. Is there a way to do it?

Here's what my code looks like.

```
CustomScrollView(
                          slivers: <Widget>[
                            SliverAppBar(
                              expandedHeight: 200.0,
                              floating: true,
                              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                                background: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    <my custom widget tree>
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            <other sliver widgets>
                          ],
                        ),
```

Comment: GestureDetector is used to detect every gestures.

Comment: But CustomScrollView.slivers only takes a list of sliver widgets, if I wrap it inside a GestureDetector, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the sliverAppBar with NotificationListener and listen for ScrollNotifications
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html

Comment: Could you please give some more details as to how to implement the same. I am editing the question with some code. I would really be grateful if you could look at it and suggest how I go   about the same.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I come too late, but @Yogesh was right with the GestureDetector.
Put it in the FlexibleSpace background property and wrap all its content.

Sample:

```
SliverAppBar(
    ...
    flexibleSpace: 
        FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: 
                GestureDetector(
                    onVerticalDragEnd: ((details) {
                        if (details.primaryVelocity! < -50) {
                            /// For example, pop the current screen
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                        }
                    }),
                    child: ...
                ),
        ),
)
```